# Writing python variable in a file

Tags: python

How would I save variable such as firstname, surname and passwords in a text document from the python!

```
print ("Hello, stranger! What is your name?")
    firstname = input()
    print ("Welcome,", firstname, "! What is your surname?")
    surname = input()
    print ("Account registred!" "Please choose your password!")
    password = input ()
    print ("Re-type your desired password!")
    passwordre = input ()
    if str(password) == str(passwordre):
        print ("Your account has finished!")
    while str(password)!= str(passwordre):
        print ("Password don't match! Account not finished!")
        print ("Try again!")
        print ("Re-type your desired password!")
        passwordre = input ()
        if str(password) == str(passwordre):
             print ("Your account has finished")
             break
```

Comment: Google sometime, maybe?

Comment: Why don't you `open` the file and just `write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(firstname, surname, password)`!!!

Comment: @KristensTaurins: How could you miss the chapter ["Reading and Writing Files"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the Python tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your `input()` that you use Python3.

Then to write in a file you can do so:

```
with open("filename.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write("firstname={}\n".format(firstname))
    myfile.write("surname={}\n".format(surname))
    myfile.write("password={}\n".format(password))
```

But I am not sure exactly what you try to achieve... You could also simply write all on a single line without descriptions:

```
    myfile.write("{} {} {}\n".format(firstname, surname, password))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is:

```
with open('file\path\and\name.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("{firstname};{surname};{password}".format(firstname=firstname, surname=surname, password=password)
```

Personally I would recommend you to look at the YAML (PyYaml) module for storing data. Also, it's a bad idea to store a password unencrypted.